# How do you write a SelectMany from a Task in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, language-ext

I would like to write a SelectMany monadic bind from a Task in F#.  How would I write the following C# code which uses [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) in F#?

`Task<int> result = from task in Task.Run<int>(() => 40) select task + 2;`

Comment: What are you trying to do? This doesn't compile in C# and would be really weird even if it did. It's not a `SelectMany` either, just a `Select`.

Comment: If you have an iterator that produces values asynchronously, you should be using `IAsyncEnumerable` in C#. The equivalent in F# is provided by the [AsyncSeq](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/) library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right!  The example C# code I was using was not even correct!

Comment: changed description to say that it works with language-ext for C#.

If you the reader, find yourself here and do not understand what a monadic bind is, this is a great example http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html (it uses Haskell but I think is one of the best examples I've seen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the F# [TaskBuilder library](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) to get the F# computation expression (monadic syntax) for tasks. With this, you can rewrite your example as:

```
let result = task {
  let! t = Task.Run<int>(() => 40)
  return t + 2 }
```

Comment: Using base F#, this is what I ended up doing.

  let task = async {
        let! x = async { return 40}
        return x + 2
       }

Comment: Yup! If you do not particularly mind whether you use tasks or asyncs, then this is even better :-)